# Convert borrowed_iterator<reverse_view<T>> to borrowed_iterator<T>

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I have buffer: `char line[1024]` which contains a line read from a file.

I want to find the last new-line (`\n`) in it, then replace all `,` with   (space) before it.

The code I came up with:

```cpp
const auto end = rng::find(line | rng::views::reverse, '\n'); // Find last occurrence of `\n`
rng::replace(line, end, ',', ' '); // Replace all `,` with ` ` before it
```

But it doesn't work because the type of `line` is a simple pointer, while `end` is a `borrowed_iterator<reverse_view<T>>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> while `end` is a `borrowed_iterator<reverse_view<T>>`.

In fact, the type of `end` is just `std::reverse_iterator<char*>`, you can use [`base()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/base) to get the underlying base
iterator:

```
rng::replace(line, end.base(), ',', ' ');
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/8MeWq16zj)

Comment: Okay.. I have no clue. I remember trying this, and it didn't work, now it does... Well, issue solved I guess.

Thank you.

Edit: Maybe IntelliSense was trolling me..